# Finding average inputbox VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a lot of grades in column L. I want an inputbox to come up and then i want to write the student ID for a student which is in column A. I was wondering if there was a way you could calculate the average of all the grades for the student with the student_id only by using the student_id?
something like this but this doesn't work:

```
 Dim StudentID As String
 Dim LastRow As Long
 Dim cell As Range
 Dim sum As Long
 Dim RowCount As Long



 StudentID = InputBox("Please enter a Student_ID:")
 LastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

 sum = 0
 RowCount = 0

 For Each cell In Range("A:A2" & LastRow)
 If cell.Value = StudentID Then 
 sum = sum + Cells(cell.Row, 12)
 RowCount = RowCount + 1
 Next cell

 avg = sum / RowCount
 MsgBox avg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have some syntax errors in your code.

```
Sub GetStudentAverage()
    Dim StudentID As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim sum As Long
    Dim RowCount As Long

    StudentID = InputBox("Please enter a Student_ID:")
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    sum = 0
    RowCount = 0

    For Each cell In Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
        If cell.Value = StudentID and IsNumeric(Cells(cell.Row, 12)) Then
            sum = sum + Cells(cell.Row, 12)
            RowCount = RowCount + 1
        End If
    Next cell

    If RowCount > 0 Then
        avg = sum / RowCount
    Else
        avg = "No Matches Found!"
    End If
    MsgBox avg
End Sub
```

You missed an `End If` and the range wasnt right. Also to avoid a division by 0, just a short check if rowcount is  > 0.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I get a type mismatch error here: sum = sum + Cells(cell.Row, 12)

Comment: Could it be because some of the grades are letters? I only want the average of all the numbers that are in column L

Comment: @ChrisTJ Yes, it checks now if its a number

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be achieved with a formula

```
=AVERAGEIFS(L:L,A:A,"StudentID")
```

or more simply in VBA

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim StudentID As Variant
    Dim avg As Variant

    StudentID = Application.InputBox("Please enter a Student ID:")
    If Not StudentID = False Then
        avg = Application.AverageIfs(Columns(12), Columns(1), StudentID)
        If Not IsError(avg) Then MsgBox avg
    End If
End Sub
```